# Hook script is active for 2nd repository, but not configured: Tortoise SVN

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hook, tortoisesvn, pre-commit

On my C: drive in Windows, I have a repository 'server' with the folder structure trunk, tags and branches as proposed by Tortoise.
It is filled with some Text files in the trunk folder for testing purpose.
A hook script`'pre-commit.bat`  is placed in the `server\hooks` folder.
The repo browser is opened on the server folder. The properties of the top repo folder are opened and a local hook script is selected by 'New'.
The command line is given, the path and name of the batch file.

Contents of the batch is:

```
echo "<full path>\pre-commit.bat". >%~dp0%USERNAME%_pre-commit.txt
```

This works and the text file is created with the name and path of the hook script batch file.

Now, 1st thing curious: after reboot, the property is not visible any more.

2nd, on another repository also on C: drive, when committing this same batch file is executed and the text file is created in the hooks folder of the 2nd directory.
But no hook script is assigned in the properties of this repository.

Is there a way to show the configured hook scripts of the repository?
Now, I cannot even remove the hook script. The only way is to delete the batch file or fill it with an empty line.

Comment: What is the period character, following the script name, for?

Comment: Just a character. Has no meaning, its copied from the original script i copied from.